# Related custom theming OF OPEN EDX

Tags: linux, ubuntu, devstack, openedx, edx

i am using devstack hawthorn problem i am facing is , i created a folder parallel to open-edx project where i cloned it. folder structure i created is edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes/my-theme inside my-theme lms and cms is there and further static files in both and i put o studio-logo.png in cms images folder to check custom theme is working or not and in studio-shell cmd edx/etc directory opened studio.yml and changed variable
COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS: [
“/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes”
]
ENABLE_COMPREHENSIVE_THEMING: true
DEFAULT_SITE_THEME: “my-theme”
and run cmd paver update_assets
’
Build failed running pavelib.assets.update_assets: Subprocess return code: 1’
please help@BbrSofiane or please tell i created wrong structure or file inside cms and lms not correct[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbyT1.png)

Comment: First thing is You no need to out your custom theme inside "edx-platform" especially in devstack you can put in "edx-themes" directory. then, check the theme structure here. https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/configuration/changing_appearance/theming/enable_themes.html#enable-themes  
if its devstack then use "make lms-static" and "make studio-static". No need to run it inside the container. Check documentation here(https://github.com/edx/devstack/tree/open-release/hawthorn.master).

Comment: Ps, if there is no specific reason to use Hawthorn, then use the latest Koa version.

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne not working i tried your way but i used previous structure and got this while running.
rtlcss: Warning! No config present, using defaults.
Saving: /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes/edge.edx.org/lms/static/css/bootstrap/lms-main-rtl.css
rtlcss /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes/edge.edx.org/lms/static/css/discussion/lms-discussion-bootstrap.css /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/themes/edge.edx.org/lms/static/css/discussion/lms-discussion-bootstrap-rtl.css